# For loop with range in django template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, for-loop, django-templates

How can I make a for loop with `range` function in django template?
I want to search in three lists by using this structure.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
{% for i in range(number) %}
    {{ my_list.i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply use use Pythonic round brackets inside curly brackets. Also, it's not that simple to get from dict using variable.
You can try creating a custom template tags.

Create file in your app: "`your_project/your_app/templatetags/custom_tags.py`" (and empty "`__init__.py`" in the same folder):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='get_range') 
def get_range(number):
    return range(number)

@register.filter(name='get_from_dict') 
def get_from_dict(my_dict, i):
    return my_dict.get(i, None)
```

And then in template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{% for i in number|get_range %}
    {{ my_list|get_from_dict:i }}
{% endfor %}
```